# Template Mutual Recursion

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, libraries

I would like to have in my library a template function `func` such that the user can overload it with its own types. The problem is that my type system is of the form

`T := A<T>, B<T>, C`

As such, `template<class T> void func(A<T>);` needs `template<class T> void func(B<T>);` if it is specialised with `T = B<C>`. Reciprocally, if we instantiate `func(B<T>)` with `T = A<C>`, the `B<T>` specialisation needs the `A<T>` specialisation.

The problem until here could be solved declaring the template functions in some common header.

What I don't know how to approach is how to make this type system extensible. I would like that the user can define her own type `template<class T> class D<T>;` and implement her own `template<class T> void func(D<T>);`. In this case, I don't know how the user could forward declare her type so that in the specialisation `A<D<C>>` the function `void func(A<T>);` is able to find `void func(D<T>);`.

Is there any standard way of doing this?

Edit minimal working example of the problem:

// in A.hpp

```
namespace ns {
template<class T> struct A { T t; };
template<class T>
void fun (A<T> a) { fun(a.t); }
}
```

// B.hpp

```
namespace ns {
template<class T> struct B { T t; };
template<class T>
void fun (B<T> b) { fun(b.t); }
```

// C.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
namespace other {
template<class T>
struct C {};
}

namespace ns {
template<class T>
void fun(other::C<T> c) { std::cout << "C" << std::endl; }
}
```

// main.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
#include "C.hpp"

namespace ns {
void f () {
    fun(A<B<other::C<int>>>());
}
}


int main () {
    ns::f();
}
```

This example doesn't compile. It just compiles if we reorder the includes in `main.cpp` as

```
#include "C.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
#include "A.hpp"
```

Now, this is clearly a hack. With this design the user will not be able to instantiate both `A<B<C<int>>>` and `B<A<C<int>>>`. A solution to this would be to forward declare `A` and `B` in some other template and include it in both `A.hpp` and `B.hpp`. The problem now comes when you try to let the user of the library define her own types. If the user of the library defines her own type `template<class T> class D;`, she cannot forward declare, and then, if she tries to instantiate `A<D<C<int>>>`, the compilation will fail.

In this example the namespace `other` represents a namespace over which I don't have control, and `C` represents a preexisting class in some other library. This can be thought as some `boost` class or similar. The `ns` namespace is the one that my library defines.

Comment: Please show some actual code.

Comment: I could guess what you mean by "of the form", but I could easily be wrong.  Actual code sketching the idea gets rid of much of that ambiguity.  `T := A<T>` is at the very least abuse of a reusing `T` to mean two different things on the same statement, and I am uncertain if that comma indicates some strange recusion or it is just a list of what `T` can be.  Actual code by editing the question demonstrating your plan please (this code should compile)

Comment: By `:=` I meant to define a grammar on the term `T`.

I am trying to replicate this behaviour in a short example, where the code compilation depends on the order of the includes.

Comment: @Lezkus `:=` is not really a C++ operator. I don't speak Haskell. Also I have no idea what `template D<T>;` means. That line means for me that you are trying to make an explicit instantiation with a syntax error because `class` is missing. I don't have the same mental model of how template works. I would really like to help you, but I need to understand the problem. Show a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: The easiest way to solve this is to tell your user to define `fun(X)` in the same namespace `X` is defined. So defining `fun(other::C<T> c)` in `namespace other` should solve the problem.

Comment: That is true, although I wouldn't want to pollute the `boost` namespace. Furthermore, it wouldn't work if C is in `std`. Is there a non-intrusive solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about if `fun()` is a static method in a template class?

So you can partial specialize the class?

I mean something like

// 000.h

```
#ifndef h_000__h
#define h_000__h

namespace ns
 {
   template <typename T>
   struct foo;
 }

#endif
```

// 001.h

```
#ifndef h_001__h
#define h_001__h

#include <iostream>

#include "000.h"

namespace ns
 {
   template<class T>
   struct A
    { T t; };

   template <typename T>
   struct foo<A<T>>
    {
      static void fun (A<T> a)
       { std::cout << "A<T> fun" << std::endl; foo<T>::fun(a.t); }
    };
 }

#endif
```

// 002.h

```
#ifndef h_002__h
#define h_002__h

#include <iostream>

#include "000.h"

namespace ns
 {
   template <typename T>
   struct B
    { T t; };

   template <typename T>
   struct foo<B<T>>
    {
      static void fun (B<T> a)
       { std::cout << "B<T> fun" << std::endl; foo<T>::fun(a.t); }
    };
 }

#endif
```

// 003.h

```
#ifndef h_003__h
#define h_003__h

#include <iostream>

#include "000.h"

namespace other
 {
   template <typename T>
   struct C
    { };
 }

namespace ns
 {
   template <typename T>
   struct foo<other::C<T>>
    {
      static void fun (other::C<T> a)
       { std::cout << "C<T> fun" << std::endl; }
    };
 }

#endif
```

// main.cpp

```
#include "001.h"
#include "002.h"
#include "003.h"

namespace ns
 {
   void f ()
    {
      using type = A<B<other::C<int>>>;

      foo<type>::fun(type{});
    }
 }

int main ()
 {
   ns::f(); // print A<T> fun \n B<T> fun \n C<T> fun \n
 }
```